# SBCL Error Messages

Tags: common-lisp

When I am using SBCL (my favourite implementation) I often see this sort of error message in the REPL

```
CL-USER> (vgplot:fred) ; Evaluation aborted on
#<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Symbol ~S not found in the ~A package." {1004289123}>. CL-USER>
```

I presume the message is meant to say "Symbol FRED not found in the VGPLOT package."

I imagine I have done something wrong in building SBCL (though I can't seem to find what exactly) , just wondering if anyone can offer advice on how to make this go away as it is annoying.

Comment: Are you using SLIME? Do you get into the debugger first, or does it just print the "; Evaluation aborted" bit right away?

Comment: That seems to be the (unreadably) printed representation of an error object. The string there is not a complete error message, but a format string intended the help the system to present the error to the user. In the debugger proper you should see the message as intended.

Comment: so yes, using slime and in slime the error appears properly. however having this appear in the repl buffer is annoying as one does not get a history of what happened precisely. I can certainly understand that this is an unreadable object, but why does it print like this? A slime interaction maybe? tks

Comment: I don't know. It's possible that it is a slime REPL thing: I don't see it in an SBCL started at the command line. You could try asking on the slime mailing list.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, it's just the normal printing of the condition object. I don't know if there's a way to suppress it or change it to print aesthetically; it's never bothered me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
(defmethod print-object :around ((condition simple-condition) stream)
  (print-unreadable-object (condition stream)
    (apply #'format stream (simple-condition-format-control condition)
                           (simple-condition-format-arguments condition))
    (terpri stream)
    (call-next-method)))
```

This will add the formatted description of all `simple-condition`s (of which `sb-int:simple-reader-error` is one) to their printed form.  I wouldn't really consider this a "good idea" and it might have some unintended consequences.

A much better solution would be to modify slime/swank to print this information itself, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Actually, this is probably the  way to go. Xach is also right - its not a killer, just a minor annoyance - but i will accept this answer. Thanks all for your help!